# Angular Chart JS v2 adjust border colors

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

Does anyone know how to adjust the colors, in particular the border colors in the updated Angular Chart JS for the Pie Charts? I have tried every possible option I can think of and can not get the border colors to change.

here is the code:

```
$scope.colors = [{ // facebook blue
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.5)',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
  pointBorderColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)'
},
  { // twitter blue
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,0.5)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,1)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,0.8)'
  }];
```

Here is my jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/rilehe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Does anyone have any insight to this problem?

Comment: Looks as if that's a bug that is about to get fixed: https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/pull/462